# Exception Inflating on Navigation View using RecyclerView, Fragment, and Activity with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a program that will show some data to a fragment with a recyclerview and using json file for the data, i have tried this before and it's working properly, but when i use a bottom navigation, i meet this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{smktelkom.student.profil/smktelkom.student.profil.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at smktelkom.student.profil.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating smktelkom.student.profil:navigation/navigasinya line 41
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:131)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:419)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:221)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2331)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1386)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1659)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1905)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3715)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at smktelkom.student.profil.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: smktelkom.student.profil.More.MoreFragment must be a subclass of class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    at androidx.navigation.NavDestination.parseClassFromName(NavDestination.java:111)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator$Destination.onInflate(FragmentNavigator.java:310)
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:143)
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:172)
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:122)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:419) 
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:221) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2331) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1386) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1659) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1905) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3715) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at smktelkom.student.profil.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

and this is my class file and navigation file in case you need it

```
package smktelkom.student.profil

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // navigation_bottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

    navigation_bottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

        onNavDestinationSelected(item, Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment))

    }


}
}
```

yeah this MainActivity is just this nothing else and the exception is linking to this class and i can't find the problem

this is the navigation file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigasinya"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_profil">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profil"
        android:name="smktelkom.student.profil.Profil.ProfilFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_profil"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profil">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_profil_to_main2Activity"
            app:destination="@id/main2Activity"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_hobi"
        android:name="smktelkom.student.profil.Hobi.HobiFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_hobi"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hobi">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_hobi_to_main3Activity"
            app:destination="@id/main3Activity"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_makanan"
        android:name="smktelkom.student.profil.Makanan.MakananFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_makanan"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_makanan">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_makanan_to_main4Activity"
            app:destination="@id/main4Activity"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_more"
        android:name="smktelkom.student.profil.More.MoreFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_more"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_more">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_more_to_main5Activity"
            app:destination="@id/main5Activity"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/main2Activity"
        android:name="smktelkom.student.profil.Main2Activity"
        android:label="activity_main2"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main2" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/main5Activity"
        android:name="smktelkom.student.profil.Main5Activity"
        android:label="activity_main5"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main5" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/main3Activity"
        android:name="smktelkom.student.profil.Main3Activity"
        android:label="activity_main3"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main3" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/main4Activity"
        android:name="smktelkom.student.profil.Main4Activity"
        android:label="activity_main4"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main4" />
</navigation>
```

i have searching another problem that's same like me and their answer is to put the android:name below the id and i've already tried it and still nothing fixed

this is my fragment class

```
package smktelkom.student.profil.More
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.app.Fragment
import android.os.Build

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_more.*
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject
import smktelkom.student.profil.News
import smktelkom.student.profil.NewsAdapter
import smktelkom.student.profil.R
import java.io.InputStream

class MoreFragment : Fragment() {

    private val TAG : String = "News"
    private lateinit var linearLayoutManager:LinearLayoutManager
    private lateinit var mAdapter: NewsAdapter

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        val jsonString:String = readJsonFromKotlinFile()
        val newsList : ArrayList<News> = parseJsonStringToNewsList(jsonString)

        mAdapter = NewsAdapter(newsList)
        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
        return view
    }

    private fun parseJsonStringToNewsList(jsonString: String): ArrayList<News> {
        val newsList :ArrayList<News> = ArrayList<News>(0)
        val newsArray = JSONArray(jsonString)
        var i = 0
        var numIterations = newsArray.length()
        while(i < numIterations){
            val newsObject:JSONObject = newsArray.getJSONObject(i)
            val news = News()
            news.news_title = newsObject.getString("news_title")
            news.news_image_url = newsObject.getString("news_image_url")
            news.news_source = newsObject.getString("news_source")
            news.news_detail = newsObject.getString("news_detail")
            news.news_url = newsObject.getString("news_url")
            news.id = newsObject.getInt("id")
            newsList.add(news)
            i++
        }
        return newsList
    }

    private fun readJsonFromKotlinFile(): String {
        var inputString = ""
        try {
            val inputStream:InputStream = activity.assets.open("news_data_file.json")
            inputString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use{it.readText()}
            Log.d(TAG,inputString)
        } catch (e:Exception){
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
        }
        return inputString
    }


}
```

well, i think there's no problem with this class because the exception didn't mention it. Just in case you need it

and this is my fragment XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorKuning"
    tools:context="smktelkom.student.profil.More.MoreFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried to search this problem but there's no question like my problem is. 
I hope everyone can help me.

Thank You

Comment: Yudhistira Arda have a look here https://www.raywenderlich.com/361-android-fragments-tutorial-an-introduction-with-kotlin

Comment: You've got the wrong `Fragment` class imported in `MoreFragment` – `import android.app.Fragment;`. That should be `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`.

Comment: oh okay i'll try it

Comment: i didn't see that